# How to intergrate tornado server into voltton agent

Tags: python, tornado, volttron

I'm new to Volttron. What I need is to integrate Tornado server into a Volttron agent. My current approach is to start a new thread when agent starts and start a Tornado loop in this thread. Is there any better ways to do this? Thanks

Comment: @Fian I've already edit the question.

Comment: You may want to consider running the server in a different process launched by the agent: testing should be easier, and working with isolated processes will decrease the chances of making concurrency-related risky decisions.